# TypeScript + JavaScript: Is not a function at x?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript

I am new to TypeScript and I'm running into a bug within my AngularJS + TypeScript/JavaScript app.

I have a service that looks a little like this:

```
module myApp {

    'use strict';

    export interface IActionItem {
        name: String;
        link?: String;
        icon: String;
        action?: any;
        className: String;
        order: Number;
    }

    export interface IActionItemsService {
        getActionItems() : IActionItem[];
    }

    class ActionItemsService implements IActionItemsService {

        private activeActionItemClass:String = 'active_menu_item';
        private actionItems:IActionItem[] = [
            {
                name: 'Search',
                icon: 'magnifier',
                action: this.search,
                className: 'visible',
                order: 2
            }
        ];

        constructor() {

        }

        private search(actionItem:IActionItem) {

            this.toggleActiveClass(actionItem);

        }

        private toggleActiveClass(actionItem:IActionItem) {
            // do some stuff with the actionItem className
        }

    }
}
```

...A controller that handles setting an array of action items to the scope.
And just a simple HTML page that handles a click action:

```
<div class="list_menu_options" ng-repeat="actionItem in vm.actionItems | orderBy:'order':true ">

    <a ng-class="actionItem.className"
            ng-click="actionItem.action(actionItem)">
        <span class="icon-{{actionItem.icon}}"></span>
        {{ actionItem.name }}
    </a>

</div>
```

Everything seems to be working as expected (and TypeScript compiles to JavaScript without error), but when I click on my search item, I see:

```
TypeError: this.toggleActiveClass is not a function
at Object.ActionItemsService.search [as action]
```

I'm sure I'm misusing something somewhere due to a minimal understanding of TypeScript, but I can't seem to find it. Any suggestions?

Comment: Here, `action` is a property of the `actionItem` object - in my example, I only have one `actionItem` whose `action` is referencing the `search` function in the `actionItemService` class.

Comment: Yeah right.. I noticed it after i posted that comment and removed it.. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is because `action` function being a part of the object (literal) is not an instance of the actual class that implements the reference to its `action` property, `search` @

```
      private actionItems:IActionItem[] = [{
            name: 'Search',
            icon: 'magnifier',
            action: this.search, //<-- this one
            className: 'visible',
            order: 2
        }
    ];
```

Hence when you invoke the function via `actioItem.action(..)`, the context (`this`) of the function execution will be that object literal and not the intended instance of the class that contains `toggleActiveClass`.

You can [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) (or you can use [angular.bind](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.bind) as well) the function reference assigned to `action` property to be of the actual `ActionItemsService` instance by doing `action: this.search.bind(this),`

i.e

```
   {
        name: 'Search',
        icon: 'magnifier',
        action: this.search.bind(this), //<-- this one
        className: 'visible',
        order: 2
    }
```

Or you could also use [arrow operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) for lexical context resolution, i.e

```
   action: (itm:IActionItem)=> this.search(itm:IActionItem),
```

Comment: Perfect! Worked like a charm. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you rewrite `toggleActiveClass` and `search` as lambdas?  Depending on how these methods are called, `this` may be pointing to the wrong thing.  Using a lambda will force `this` to be lexically scoped - meaning it will always point to the class instead of it being dependent on how the function was actually called.

```
    private search = (actionItem:IActionItem) => {
        this.toggleActiveClass(actionItem);
    }

    private toggleActiveClass = (actionItem:IActionItem) => {
        // do some stuff with the actionItem className
    }
```

Comment: Hmm, the error goes away. However, it doesn't appear that the `ng-click` is invoking `search` anymore. I have my console logging 'searching' within the 'search' function. It logs as expected with my sample above, but not when using `toggleActiveClass` and `search` as lambdas.